# How do I use tab index in ui:repeat in primefaces?

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

I use one `ui:repeat` in my jsf page and I want to use tabindex on each element of the list.
I tried with the below code. 
Please help me out of this issue.

```
<div class="meta-list">
   <p:outputPanel>
      <ui:repeat var="com2" value="#{masterDataBean.mylist}" varStatus="loop" tabindex="1">  
         <p:commandLink value="#{com.value} " action="#{masterDataBean.doSomething}" tabindex="2">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{masterDataBean.selecteData}" value="#{com2}" />
         </p:commandLink>
      </ui:repeat>
   </p:outputPanel>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no attribute like `tabindex` on `ui:repeat` tag? What do you actually want to do?

Comment: For indexing you can `#{loop.index}` as of `varStatus` value.

Comment: I want to iterate all the elements using tab button in the list. @Prakash

Answer (score 2):

You can set `tabindex` of `p:commandLink` with dynamic iteration index value using `#{loop.index}` of `varStatus="loop"` on `ui:repeat` tag, as following:

```
<div class="meta-list">
   <p:outputPanel>
      <ui:repeat var="com2" value="#{masterDataBean.mylist}" varStatus="loop">  
         <p:commandLink value="#{com.value}"
             action="#{masterDataBean.doSomething}" tabindex="#{loop.index}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{com2}"
                target="#{masterDataBean.selecteData}" />
         </p:commandLink>
      </ui:repeat>
   </p:outputPanel>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mihir: if I am understanding your question, that should do the trick!